# Mapping interchangeably terms such as Weight to Mass for QAnswering NLP

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, synonym

I've been working on a Question Answering engine in C#. I have implemented the features of most modern systems and are achieving good results. Despite the aid of Wordnet , one problem I haven't been able to solve yet is changing the user input to the correct term.

For example

```
changing Weight -> Mass
changing Tall   -> Height
```

My question is about the existence of some sort of resource that can aid me in this task of changing the terms to the correct terms.

Thank You

Comment: "weight" and "mass" are not interchangeable. Also, why would "height" be any more correct than "length" or "distance"? I think you might need to put some more work into establishing your requirements.

Comment: I know that weight and mass are not interchangeable , but people use them as if they are, and that's the problem I'm trying to solve. When you have a question like "how much does the earth weigh?". The user is not likely seeking a value in Newtons which would be the correct answer, however the user would more likely expecting the actual mass. For tall , height would be more correct because tall is a vertical length, thus length or distance is more broad than height. So with a question like "how tall is mount everest". You could recognize a relationship with height than with elevation.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know how to do this effectively requires having a large corpus of user query sessions and a happiness measure on sessions, and then finding correlations between substituting word x for word y (possibly given some context z) that improves user happiness.

Here is a reasonable paper on [generating query substitutions](http://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/ism293/Spring09/material/papers/lec5/jones-www2006-generating-query-subs.pdf).

And here is a new paper on [generating synonyms from anchor text](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/179963/paper-final.pdf), which doesn't require a query log.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all the synsets in WordNet for both `Mass` and `Weight` I can see that there is no shared synset and thus there is no meaning in common.  Words that actually do have the same meaning can be matched by means of their synset labels, as I'm sure you've realized.

In my own natural language engine (http://nlp.abodit.com) I allow users to use any synset label in the grammar they define but I would still create two separate grammar rules in this case, one recognizing questions about mass and one recognizing questions about weight.

However, there are also files for Wordnet that give you class relationships between synsets too.  For example, if you type 'define mass' into my demo page you'll see:-

```
4. wn30:synset-mass-noun-1
the property of a body that causes it to have weight in a gravitational field
--type--> wn30:synset-fundamental_quantity-noun-1
--type--> wn30:synset-physical_property-noun-1
ITokenText, IToken, INoun, Singular
```

And if you do the same for 'weight' you'll also see that it too has a class relationship to 'physical property'.

In my system you can write a rule that recognizes a question about a 'physical property' and perhaps a named object and then try to figure out which physical property they are likely to be asking about.  And, perhaps, if you can't match maybe just tell them all about the physical properties of the object.

The method signature in my system would be something like ...

```
 ... QuestionAboutPhysicalProperties (... IPhysicalProperty prop,
                                          INamedObject obj, ...)
```

... and in code I would look at the properties of obj and try to find one called 'prop'.